# RazorLight.RazorLightException in FluentEmail (2.8.0) when being used in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, razorlight

I am trying to use FluentEmail 2.8.0 in an Azure Function. However, I had the following exception.

> RazorLight.RazorLightException: Can't load metadata reference from the entry assembly. Make sure PreserveCompilationContext is set to true in *.csproj file

I have added the following into csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <PreserveCompilationReferences>true</PreserveCompilationReferences>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But I still get the same error.

Anyone has come across this before?

Environment: .NET Core 3.1, Azure Functions v3

Answer (score 1):

At least I am able to find a workaround.

1. Do not use the razor renderer from fluent email factory
2. Use the following

   ```
            var engine = new RazorLightEngineBuilder()
                        .UseEmbeddedResourcesProject(typeof(EmailService))
                        .UseMemoryCachingProvider()
                        .SetOperatingAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                        .Build();
            var result = engine.CompileRenderStringAsync(templateName, template, viewModel);
   ```

...

then use `_fluentEmail.Create()...Body(result, true)`

add the missing nuget package `System.Threading.AccessControl` also.